# Issue with pgcrypto pgp_pub_encrypt

Tags: postgresql, encryption, pgp, pgcrypto

I have been trying to test the pgcrypto extension in Postgres but am having some difficulties.  When I try and encrypt data, I keep getting a

```
ERROR:  No encryption key found

********** Error **********

ERROR: No encryption key found
SQL state: 39000
```

I used Kleopatra to create a pub/private key but it does not seem to work.

Test Table:

```
CREATE TABLE notes
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  note bytea,
  description text,
  CONSTRAINT pk_notes PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Any suggestions would be fantastic.

Here is my Insert code:

```
INSERT INTO "notes"("note")
VALUES(pgp_pub_encrypt('This test data', dearmor(
'-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v2

mQENBFUNhxMBCADXMrvdx/UmVdH0ABZdmUIjCe3/lh7s7G6AFRjryFfuZbcj62//
LBxRq2QsONxuzNq8HIwssuLQxOtU9yqv5U49TGl4wuu+2jGorKnbDIKCIrM7tFpi
JSOeClsDJer9I+UrXbYQLSoN/nyYUxl5ColxnvmWnQagZH71L5eLKke/W4DJXcgW
N3Yt6vfi4wOFQ3IdVQeMP8b6ehZjbTU2+eDShvsLhkUYD5//OGjpshsBocnIvZBe
...
...
...
...
B/0SD4A2b6buRnwyDtJ+eTBjQTVT3ISSgTtwtmtLQvy4/3r95G/3UdB/+ZtB1ygB
H/1h9gh2NbonRS0uoIvhsy81/G+qXngnvuIL2K3SeDV5rF9AMEX1NWeoX73GhdD2
X6Er82DfC8cowqWge4yM55FRMo3k2Upjo004ofDmpj/wbJDspU/iDIUHWYv+upEJ
0yeVukQLaRe3/IMqd0lSHW0piDLP6FvG98suZOPZS6ivYCE1Y7cFUPxxPAZRvxVO
dXbPRUw8vBHBDHoJ8h+zcBz4kinj4I28gXNIzaMLZU6+Ju+GicAMwh3iS2TBSM8y
fZn+OwxJfeAUq9sw94A3hmPU
=2/+P
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----')));
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:  I thought I could use Kleopatra to create the public/private pair.
Somehow I got a key pair but they did not work.
When I created the keys using the **gpg** command line, it worked.

Pretty straight forward:

> gpg --gen-key

Answer the questions.
When the keys are generated you need to export them.

> gpg --export-secret-key -a "{email that you used to create key}" > secret.key
>
> gpg --export -a "{email that you used to create key}" > public.key

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into some trouble that I was not able to repeat with a new key, so I figure I'll share what did work:

## From the Top

```sh
gpg --full-generate-key
# Real-Name: testname
# Email:
# Comment:
# Okay
# Passphrase: foobar
```

```sh
gpg --armor --export 'testname'
```

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo_data (data BYTEA);
INSERT INTO foo_data
SELECT pgp_pub_encrypt('x', dearmor(
'-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
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=3n/6
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----'
)) AS data;
```

```sh
gpg --armor --export-secret-key 'testname'
```

```
SELECT pgp_pub_decrypt(data, dearmor(
'-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
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=pUwd
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----'
), 'foobar') AS data FROM foo_data;
```

## Bonus: Using environment and postgres variables

```sql
\set pgp_public_key `gpg --armor --export 'Test User'`
SELECT :'pgp_public_key';

\set pgp_private_key `echo "$PGP_PRIVATE_KEY"`
SELECT :'pgp_private_key';
```